# Do multiple user accounts on the Wii U all share the same save data for games?

Tags: wii-u, splatoon

My little brother disgustingly hogs my Wii U so much and some games I like to do myself, like Splatoon, I can't because he played the ever living life out of it. If I make another Wii U Mii profile and picking it, would it treat the Splatoon save file as exclusive to the main Wii U Mii profile?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Splatoon can have separate accounts on the same WiiU.

> **What are the benefits/tradeoffs for each user having their own account versus all the users sharing a single account? What would you
>   recommend?**
>
> The benefits of multiple accounts are having their own saves (for most
>   games, not all) and having their own save states and restore points
>   for VC titles. You also get to lay out the menu how you like, if you
>   care about that sort of thing.
>
> Source
>   [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wiiu/comments/2mwzwu/help_me_understand_nnid_multiple_user_profiles/)
>
> ---
>
> **Will each Wii U user be able to have its own file? Or will it be like Smash where everything is shared between users? Any confirmation
>   regarding this?**
>
> I think gamexplain's QA video says it's a file per user.
>
> **How many save files does Splatoon have?**
>
> Just the one per account.
>
> Source Gamefaqs
>   [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805617-splatoon/71859726) and
>   [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805617-splatoon/72178173)

Answer (score -1):

think you can have separate accounts on WiiU with separate game saved data files, so you can start afresh on a new account.